# How to get username in Next-Auth for Github Provider?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm using https://next-auth.js.org/ for my login system, but i cannot get the username from it. It's only return name, email, image, and accesstoken. But what i want is username from the GitHub account so how do i achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a little workaround

Use this endpoint to get your user info by id:
[https://api.github.com/user/[userId]](https://api.github.com/user/%5BuserId%5D)

You can get your userId from your data.user.image, which next-auth provides:
[https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/[userId]?v=4](https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/%5BuserId%5D?v=4)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there is a way if you use Prisma and postgress Get under the Account Table you'll be able to find the `providedAccountiD` and then you can send the req from [https://api.github.com/user/[userId]](https://api.github.com/user/%5BuserId%5D) the userid from the postgress account table -> providedAccountID
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way which I used to access the username is by simply configuring the GitHubProvider in the [...nextauth] file/folder the following way:

```
interface NextAuthUserWithStringId extends NextAuthUser {
 id: string;
}
    ....
GitHubProvider({
  clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID!,
  clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET!,
  profile(profile) {
    return {
      id: profile.id.toString(),
      name: profile.name || profile.login,
      email: profile.email,
      image: profile.avatar_url,
      username: profile.login,
    } as NextAuthUserWithStringId;
  },
}),
...
```

That way, when the user logs in with his Github account, you have access to his username and you can store it in your database, as long as you've defined the username field in the user model.